# Laravel5: What does the extra slash in belongsToMany('\App\Article') do?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

While going through Laracasts Laravel 5 Tutorial, the tutor mentions nothing about an extra slash before the namespace reference [ belongsToMany('\App\Article') ] in Episode 21: Many to Many Relationships. What could be its significance?

If I remove the extra \, I get an error:

> No query results for model [App\Article].

**Article.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Article extends Model 
{
     public function tags()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
     }
}
```

**App/Tag.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Article');
    }
}
```

Comment: The \ refers to the global namespace. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)

Comment: Why should I use global namespace for \App\Article and not for App\Tag or App\User? They all use the same App namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer regarding the title of your post:**

Like mentioned in the comments, the \ refers to the global namespace . Not The App namespace.

You could also do

```
public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
```

if that's more clear to you. This will also give the opportunity to click on the class to go directly to the definition of it.(in most IDE's )

**Answer regarding the error you are receiving**

> No query results for model [App\Article].

This error is mostly created if you have something like this in your controller:

```
$article = Article::findOrFail($id)
```

If the article is not found it will throw that exception. Which means that in this case the $id passed through does not exist.